# best way to do the server side rendering in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, axios, server-side-rendering, react-helmet

I am working on one website and i want there server side rendering for meta tags, title etc, I have tried 5-6 ways to do that but not working for dynamic data.
I have used reactjs, react-helmet, axios packages,
I want when user go to the blog details screens there will be only blog details meta tags. (for seo and share on social media)

Comment: For server side rendering, you can use [`Next.js`](https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html)

Answer (score 0):

Yes [Nextjs](https://nextjs.org/) works best for SSR with React, but it seem you are just trying to have a simple blog and update the meta tags and get good SEO. I'd recommend [GatsbyJS](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/) because it does all of that while also building your site as static files so you can host it on CDNs like Netlify.

Comment: I have done ssr using https://github.com/stereobooster/react-snap but when any new post added in back-end then it is not generating static pages without build, please let me know if you know how to do that